# sql server 2005 trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a table like this

```
table-1
Project-name        proj-status
-----------         -----------
pro1                progress
pro2                progress
pro3                progress
```

If I update the proj-status as completed

```
Project-name        proj-status
-----------         -----------
pro1                progress
pro2                completed
pro3                progress
```

then it should be insert into table2

```
table-2
completed prject
----------------
pro2
```

I want to do this using trigers! please help me.

Comment: I am not going to do your job for you. And remember that not all versions of SQL Server support triggers (Standard and Express don't)

Comment: @SJuan76 - I beg your pardon? Standard and Express most certainly do support triggers.

Comment: Why not just have a view that filters `table1` to those rows which are completed - it will always be correct, and you don't have to write code to update it.

Comment: I stand corrected. I remember that a long time ago I found some difference in trigger capabilities between versions of SQL Server 2000, but can't even find documentation of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an update trigger like this in the example below , i have an emp table when its employee is updated to 'completed' that employee id is copied to table emp1

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[updtrigg] 
ON  [dbo].[emp] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @emp as varchar(50)
    declare @empid as varchar(5)
    SELECT @empid = empid, @emp = employee  FROM   inserted
     if(@emp = 'completed')
     begin
        INSERT into emp1 (employee) values(@empid)
     end
END
```

Comment: Your trigger assumes that only a single row exists in `inserted`. That's not generally a safe assumption to make.

Comment: The question stated for a single update, hence the answer. If there was a batch update then trigger is not the way to go as it leads uncessary locks and i would have answered as such.

Comment: A trigger that's broken for multi-row inserts is a broken trigger. In addition, the OP just stated "if I update the proj-status to completed" - they didn't mention whether that update was going to apply to one row or many in a single statement.